# How to show Dag in UI airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I downloaded Airflow without Docker, I created a DAG folder and put the DAGS file inside, but it does not appear on the site
i do scheduler again and reset DB and reset airflow webserver but doesn't work

[image: the main files]

[image: my dags in DAGS floder]

Comment: Would you please go into your airflow cfg file and find the name parameter dag_folder?
The dag_folder parameter refers to your dag folder path.

Comment: yes i do that but nothing work with me

Comment: Please provide the information of dag from the logs folder. If there is anything wrong with dag or probably something else logs folder would have the data of error.

Comment: please if you can tell me details about what i can do in logs file ?

Comment: There would be a scheduler folder in the log folder. Open that and open the respective dag log file, and scroll till the end, at the end, you can find the errors for why dags wouldn't show up.